# C - UDP Client not completing SendTo to Echo Server

Tags: c, server, udp, echo

I'm trying to complete a simple echo server. The goal is to repeat back the message to the client. The server and client both compile. The server runs, you just need to give it a port to run on. The client has the address, the port, and the message. When the client goes through the program to the sendto section, it stop and waits there. My goal it to have it sent to the server, and the server to send it back.

I believe that the server works, or it least is in the mode to receive as it enters the while loops to do that. That part can send notes back that it works.

For the client, I've tried sending the argument directly, but also through a c-string. I've tried one hard coded in, and none of them have worked. I've been at it for many hours, so I decided to ask for help because I can't think of anything else as a newbie.

Client

```
//argv[1] address, argv[2] port, argv[3] message
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int BUF_LEN;

for (BUF_LEN = 0; argv[3][BUF_LEN] != '\0'; BUF_LEN++){
//  printf("BUF_LEN = %i\n", BUF_LEN);
}
    int s, n, port_no, r;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    char *haddr, *message;
    char buf[BUF_LEN+1];

printf("Variables created\n");

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); // create a socket for UDP

printf("Socket created as s: %i\n", s);

bzero((char *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));   // clear

server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;   //IPv4 Internet family
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);   //server address
server_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));    // server port number

printf("Server addr complete\n");

//Bind() - Not necessary

printf("Bind skipped\n");

//sendto()
    r = sendto(s, argv[3], strlen(argv[3]), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, BUF_LEN);
    printf("Message Sent");

//recvfrom()
    n = recvfrom (s, buf, BUF_LEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, &BUF_LEN);
    printf("Message Received: %s\n", buf);

close(s);

}
```

Server

```
//Argv[1] : port number
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int n; 
int MAXLINE = 512;
int sock_server, sock_client, r, len;
char buf[MAXLINE];
struct sockaddr_in my_addr, client_addr;    

//printf("Variables created\n");

sock_server = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); 

//printf("Socket created\n");

if (sock_server < 0){
    perror("Bind failed");
    exit(1);
}

bzero(&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr));       // clear

my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;           //Address Family INET
my_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));    //Server port number
my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);    // Accept from anywhere

//printf("Addresses created\n");

r = bind(sock_server, (struct sockaddr*)(&my_addr), sizeof(my_addr));
    if (r < 0) {
        perror("Bind failed");
        exit(1);
    }

printf("Read to receive\n");

while(1) {

//printf("First while loop\n");

len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    //recvfrom()
    n = recvfrom (sock_client, buf, MAXLINE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &len);

while (n > 1){
    printf("Second while loop\n");

    printf("Message Received: %s\n", buf);

    //sendto()
    sendto(sock_client, buf, n, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, len);
    n = 0;
    }
}

    close(sock_client);     //close the client socket
//printf("Connection sock_client Closed");
}
```

Comment: In the client, the `sendto` shouldn't be using `BUF_LEN`. Looks like you got it right in the server, although I would reinitialize the `len` variable before the `sendto` call.

Comment: Just to clarify @user3386109 posting... In your client, Your last argument (6th) in calling "sendto" is incorrect... the last argument should be the "sizeof" the next-to-the-last (5th) argument... in your case "sizeof(server_addr)".  You might have discovered it if you had checked the returncode from "sendto"... Additionally, you use command line arguments without ever checking "argc" to ensure your client was invoked with the appropriate number of arguments.

Comment: How do you find the return code of the sendto? I attempted to connect it to a variable with var = the sendto command, but when trying to complete that it still hangs. I've changed the line so that the last two variables say &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)); but it hangs there still, not proceeding to the printf line after it.

Comment: Besides to what @TonyB explained, I suppose you mistakenly believe that the `sendto` hangs because you don't see a `"Message Sent"` printed. The `stdout` is line-buffered, and nothing going to be printed until a `\n` character appears. The client surely hangs at `recvfrom`.

Comment: Thank you, I think you're right. After I added \n to the "message sent" it, that printf message appears. Now it waits for a response from the recvfrom. From more research it needs a \n to push it through the buffer, or a fflush(stdout) command. I'm just documenting that here in case someone else happens on this post and so that they won't need to ask the same question. Now I'll work more on the recvfrom bits to see if I can find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fixed version of the client using `sizeof(server_addr)` in the client call of `sendto`:

```
//argv[1] address, argv[2] port, argv[3] message
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  int BUF_LEN;

  for (BUF_LEN = 0; argv[3][BUF_LEN] != '\0'; BUF_LEN++){
    //  printf("BUF_LEN = %i\n", BUF_LEN);
  }

  int s, n, port_no, r;
  struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
  char *haddr, *message;
  char buf[BUF_LEN+1];

  printf("Variables created\n");

  s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); // create a socket for UDP

  printf("Socket created as s: %i\n", s);

  bzero((char *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));   // clear

  server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;   //IPv4 Internet family
  server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);   //server address
  server_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));    // server port number

  printf("Server addr complete\n");

  //Bind() - Not necessary

  printf("Bind skipped\n");

  r = sendto(s, argv[3], strlen(argv[3]), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
  printf("Message Sent");

  n = recvfrom (s, buf, BUF_LEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, &BUF_LEN);
  printf("Message Received: %s\n", buf);

  close(s);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I tried using it and it still hangs at the sendto spot.

Comment: I figured it out. In the server one it had to be this...

sendto(sock_server, buf, n, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, len);

sock_client didn't matter. You were the one that posted an answer, which helped with the first part, so I tip my hat to you good sir.